# Python property decorator not working, why?

Tags: python, python-2.7

For some reason the 'obj._max_value' and 'obj._current_value' are not getting set. I have looked at many tutorials and it seems that I am doing it correctly. Does anyone know why it is not working?

See code: https://gist.github.com/matthew-campbell/5561562

(Python 2.7)

---

Update:

```
class Progress():

  @property
  def progress_bar_length(self):
    return self._progess_bar_length

  @progress_bar_length.setter
  def progress_bar_length(self, length):
    self._progress_bar_length = length

  @progress_bar_length.deleter
  def progress_bar_length(self):
    del self.progress_bar_length
```

Comment: Don't use huge mostly irrelevant code samples, and definitely don't post links to Gists. It's recommended to reduce your problem down to its essentials, and post a code sample (as simple as you can make it) in your question. Your problem could easily have been demonstrated with <10 lines of code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `property` decorator doesn't work with old-style classes. Inherit your class from `object` to get a new-style class:

```
class Progress(object):
    # ...
```

Comment: @MattCampbell Also, Python is not Java. You most likely don't need all those properties, they only serve to slow down your program and make it *harder* to maintain (because of loads of unnecessary boilerplate).

Comment: @user4815162342 Why would you say so? I find it convenient to use. How do you know it slows down the computer?

Comment: @Valentyn Properties are fine when they actually make sense in your program, but you don't need to use them _everywhere_, e.g. to expose a "private" slot as a "public" property. This slows down the program (not the computer!) because CPython is interpreted, so there's no JIT compiler to inline all those accessor function calls. Also, in Python you can always start off with a public attribute and migrate it to a property later without loss of API compatibility. There's no reason to use a property because you *might* need to add logic in the future - you'll add it if/when you actually need it.