# Unexpected behavior when properties is used over getters and setters in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, python-decorators

I tried properties over getter and setters as in below code, when class B test function is called I expected class A setter will be called but unfortunately a new instance variable of class B is created. This behavior is observed in python 2.7.13 and it works fine in python 3.

**Code:**

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 10

    @property
    def vala(self):
        print ("Into Vala getter")
        return self.a

    @vala.setter
    def vala(self, a):
        print ("Into Vala setter")
        self.a = a

class B:
    def test(self):
        self.a = A()
        self.a.vala = 10
        print ("B.test completed")

b = B()
b.test()
```

**Output with python 2.7.13**

```
B.test completed
```

**Output with python 3**

```
Into Vala setter
B.test completed
```

My question is if this is the expected behavior how to work with composition in python 2.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [Python property decorator not working, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502133/python-property-decorator-not-working-why)
In Python 2, you need to inherit from object to get the same behavior as Python 3, otherwise you are still in old-style classes land.

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem

Comment: @VasanthAlagiriswamy please accept answers if thry do solve your problems for others to see easier as well.